# Unable to drop SQL azure table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to drop SQL azure table. However I can delete data inside the table. When using drop command, it is taken long time processing and finally this error message "Connection Failed."

Comment: Can you share the exact error (exception) you get while trying to drop?
Connection Failed can be for multiple instances. (from Pradebban Raja's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Look for the blocking processes using the dm_exec_requests dmv after issuing drop and kill the blocking sessions. This is assuming you have right permissions to drop the table, otherwise you need to check user permissions. Call stack and error message would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not concerned on specific data, you could do a truncate on the table.

```
Truncate Table [TABLENAME];
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, and the suggestion hides identifying the root cause.